# Problem in listening to multicast in multihomed Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, multicast

I am trying to write a multicast client on a machine with two NICs, and I can't make it work. I can see with a sniffer that once I start the program the NIC (eth4) start receiving the multicast datagrams: y.y.y.y. (some ip) -> z.z.z.z (multicast ip, not my eth4 NIC IP) UDP Source port: kkk (some other port) Destination port: xxx (multicast port)

However, I can't get those packets using my program (listening to port xxx on eth4).

I also added: route add 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth4

Searched the web for some examples/explanations, but it seems like I do what everybody else does. Any help will be appreciated. is there anything else to do with route/iptables?

Answer (score 2):

I found that turning off rp_filter allowed multicast data to come into my application.  When set to 1 it discarded the data that was being received at the interface.

Mike Graham